# Opensource PDF generator for Angular and Java

Tags: java, angular, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm looking for the best PDF generators for Angular and JAVA. If there's one that can be used in both would be great. The requirements I have on these PDF creators are:

1. OpenSource
2. Easy to use
3. Can be used on Enterprise level
4. Generate custom PDFs (not just print-outs of what’s on the screen)

So far I have on my list:

- iText **(discarded)**
- Apache POI
- Aspose **(discarded)**
- PDFBox
- PDF Clown **(discarded)**

Comment: I've used both iText, PDFBox and POI.  All have their issues, but we've found work-arounds for all.  Our "go to" solution lately has been POI even though it's a bit verbose

Comment: We used iText too (version 2 .XX) I know they are in version 7.XX but It cost money

Comment: @Dan Apache POI is only for JAVA, correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_POI

Comment: @Dan Is there a particular reason why you decided to use POI as your go solution. I don't like the fact that we have to create a docx first then convert it to pdf. I want to be able to create a pdf from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular if you have data on UI then you can use following libraries which have good provision to export pdf:

```
"jspdf": "^1.4.1"
"jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.4"
```

If you need customized reports and have dependency on backend then you can use **Jasper Reports** which can give more reach appearance.